# How do I fix X problem to invoke Cadence IC6.10 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: xorg, qt

I installed Cadence IC6.10 in my Ubuntu 13.10. When I tried to invoke the Cadence, I got the following error message:

```
 =============================================================

 Qt Warning: X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)8

 Extension: 139 (RENDER)

 Minor opcode: 4 (RenderCreatePicture)

 Resource id: 0x26

 ..........
 .........

=============================================================
```

I searched around and got an advice that I could add the following strings to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
============================================================

Section "Extensions"

Option "Composite" "Disable"

EndSection

============================================================
```

However, after I added these strings and rebooted Ubuntu, it was always stuck in boot screen. If I changed "*Disable*" as "*Enable*", I could reboot it successfully. But I was still not able to invoke Cadence. It still showed the same error message.

Could anyone tell me a right solution to fix this error so I could invoke Cadence successfully?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Try to add this line in `~/.bashrc` or run it every time you start your cadence IC610:

```
export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1
```